# Html layout creation from psd file measure

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I am translating a .psd layout to an Html file and related css. 
How should I translate the measure in psd file to html?
For example if I see one psd element height 20px, should I set the css height for that element to 20px? I think in this way it is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

For the html elements you can use fixed sizing, if you want to add responsiveness to the layout then use media queries. When working with fonts best practise is to use REM units.

[CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[Font sizing with rem](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)